# Javascript - .length gives me 0 length

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array is initialized

```
var Collect = [];
```

So I have a promise arguments so that I'll have a asynchronous in execution since retrieving data from firebase which then push in the array Collect takes a bit of time. Here's my code:

```
function loadTables(){
    var promise = getDataFirebase();
    promise.then(function(){
        console.log("firsst");
        return ProcessOfData();
    }).then(function(){
        console.log(Collect);            //when printed, it shows the elements collected from firebase so the array is not 0.
         console.log(Collect.length);   // but when printeed here. it gives me 0. why? 
        return EndProcessLog();
    }).then(function(){

    });         
}
```

Codes when retrieving data from firebase:

```
function getDataFirebase(){
    return new Promise (function(resolve,reject){
        refReview.on("value", function(snap){
            var data = snap.val();
            for(var key in data){              //data retrieved must be REVIEWEE NAME, REWIEVER NAME, RATING, ,CONTENT
                Collect.push({
                    "RevieweeName": data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
                    "ReviewerName": data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ",data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
                    rating:data[key].rating,
                    content: data[key].content
                })
            }//end of for loop

        }); //end of snap 
        resolve();   
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you not passing the object through the promise? Why is it some global?

Comment: hi, sorry. what do you mean not passing? quite new to promise

Comment: You need to have some response object from promise to get the data.

Like promise.getData(function(response) => {return response.data})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it not work? Because you are resolving the promise before the asynchronous method runs. The reason why the object shows the value is the console lazy loading the object.

What do you do? Move the resolve line after the for loop inside the callback.

```
refReview.on("value", function(snap) {
  var data = snap.val();
  for (var key in data) { //data retrieved must be REVIEWEE NAME, REWIEVER NAME, RATING, ,CONTENT
    Collect.push({
      "RevieweeName": data[key].revieweeID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].revieweeID.lastname),
      "ReviewerName": data[key].reviewerID.firstname.concat(" ", data[key].reviewerID.lastname),
      rating: data[key].rating,
      content: data[key].content
    })
  } //end of for loop
  resolve(); < --RIGHT

}); //end of snap 
// resolve(); <-- WRONG
```

Ideally with a promise you do not use global variables, you pass the value through the resolve.

```js
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var str = "Hello!";
  resolve(str);
});

myPromise.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: hi epascarello. Thank you very much. you explained very well hehe. ill try to reconstruct some codes so that i wont be able to use global variables.